# Create high-resolution charts with Flot on Retina displays

Tags: mobile-safari, flot, retina-display

I want to show some simple chart in my web application, but using Flot on an Apple device with Retina display looks blurry.

I use the 'normal' viewport settings:

> `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />`

and this container for Flot to draw in:

> `<div id="placeholder" style="width: 300px;height:400px;"></div>`

This is what I get:

[image]

So obivously Flot doesn't use `window.devicePixelRatio` by default, so I wanted to help out with some custom code:

```
var newWidth = $(chart.getCanvas()).attr("width") * window.devicePixelRatio;
var newHeight = $(chart.getCanvas()).attr("height") * window.devicePixelRatio;
$(chart.getCanvas()).attr("width", newWidth);
$(chart.getCanvas()).attr("height", newHeight);
chart.setupGrid();
chart.draw();
```

This in fact changes the canvas' dimensions and they keep that way even after the drawing. On the iPhone 4S it tells me the canvas dimensions are now 600 * 800 (after the drawing), but it still doesn't look crisp.

Comment: For what it worths, I submitted a pull request to the flot core that add support for retina display : https://github.com/flot/flot/pull/52

Comment: I believe this has been included in flot 0.8